# How do I export Visible/Hidden attributes to an FBX from Blender?

Tags: export, unity, .fbx

Right now Blender doesn't support exported FBXs to recognise animation keys on any visible/hidden channels on a rig.

And this is just a Blender issue.
(Maya supports visibility keys in FBX exports).

Blender not supporting visibility keys is actually stated in the Blender docs: "Blender does not export the visibility value inside animations in the FBX file."
[Link here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectsFrom3DApps.html#Blender)

I'm just wondering if anyone has a way around this?

Is there a script I can use, or something else I can tag that is exportable?  Any work around suggestions you have I'd be very grateful to receive.

I never like it when Maya beats Blender at anything, so I hope the devs can solve this one.  Unity is a patron member of the Blender Foundation, so I hope something happens from that relationship.

In the meantime, I'll take whatever suggestions you have. Thank you!